# How to implement query a resource by multi dimesions in flask-restful?

Tags: python-3.x, api, rest, flask-restful

As a new just learning flask, I have a few questions.

```
class Users(Resource):
    decorators = [...,]

    def get(self, user_id):
        """
        GET /users : all uesers
        GET /users/1 : user where user_id = 1
        """
        # do query user by user_id
```

In real business, thers is rarely queried users based on only one dimension, instead, most of the time, we need to query users based on multiple dimensions, such as

- query users by name
- query users by email address
- query users by name and create_time
- More ...

**My Questions:**

**Q1:** as I know, there is only on get method in a flask-restful resource class, how to support so many query user functions in one get methon?
many be like this,

```
def get(user_id=None, user_email=None, user_create_time=None, user_name=None):
    if user_id is None and user_email is None and user_create_time is None and user_name:
        query_user_by_name
    elif user_id is None and user_email and user_create_time is None and user_name is None:
        query_user_by_email
    ...
```

OH...HO..., It's smelly and long, really a disaster!

**Q2:** I also think that use different Resource, like:

```
    class UserNameResource(Resource):
        def get(user_name):
            query_user_by_name

    class UserNameAndCreateTimeResource(Resource):
        def get(user_name, create_time):
            query_user_by_name_and create_time

    ...
```

It's also long, ugly, and doesn't conform to restful naming rules, this is my second question.

**Q3:** Use post methon instead of get, because restful is not restricted to use POST method to query a resource. If this is Ok, so here comes my third question: how to distinguish 'create a resource' from 'query a resource' in a post method? Maybe with my limited understanding, like this?

```
class Users(Resource):
    def post(_method, **kwargs):
        if _method == 'QUERY':  # just a flag, could be others， as long as it's agreed in advance
            # query_resource, then query user by diffenent conditions
            
            if query_string in kwargs:
                # query_sring is a dict, could used to ORM query, 
                # so there is only one method for query users resouce, 
                # there is no more other query_users_funcs like 
                # query_user_by_name, query_user_id, 
                # query_user_by_name_and_email ...

               query_user_by_query_string

        if _method == 'CREATE':
            create_resource
```

I'm a newcomer to flask and restful. The above are my confusing, problems, and my own thoughts, which may be very immature.
Welcome to discuss and guide me. Thank you very much.

Comment: I recommend asking your three questions as three separate questions.

Comment: @LajosArpad Thanks, bro. In fact, this is one problem. I have only considered three immature solutions to this problem. However, I think that each solution is not very good,  so here comes the 3 questions.

Expect who can give a perfect solution, then these three problems do not exist.